# Deriving a column's data from a matching column in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So I have a table that has, employee number, employee name, supervisor number.

I want to run a query that will retrieve employee name, employee number, supervisor name and supervisor number. Only one employee doesn't have a supervisor meaning it will have to display nulls. How would I do this? I'm using Oracle SQL Plus. My attempts haven't worked at all! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT ename Employee, empno Emp#, super Manager#
FROM emp;
```

That gets me three of the columns but to be honest I don't even know where to start to get the supervisors names.

It's for university, but I'm studying for a test it's not for an assignment so no cheating happening here :).

Comment: You'll need to show us what you've tried. Also, is this for school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, and give you nulls if the employee has no supervisor:

```
SELECT empGrunt.ename Employee
     , empGrunt.empno EmpNum
     , empSuper.ename SupervisorName
     , empSuper.empno SupervisorName
FROM   emp empGrunt LEFT OUTER JOIN emp empSuper 
       ON empGrunt.super = empSuper.empno
```

Comment: So just to clarify for my understanding, grunt and super are just pseudo names given so that employee and supervisor can be distinguished? And then you retrieved only the grunt data and then outer joined the two together and said the supervisor stuff is derived from the grunt table? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `empGrunt` and `empSuper` are aliases that are given to the two different instances of the `emp` table involved in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `SupervisorNumber` is a foreign key relationship back to the `Employee` table (where it's the `EmployeeNumber` of the supervisor's record), then you need to use an outer join.

What you need in this case is a `left` join:

```
select
    e.EmployeeName,
    e.EmployeeNumber,
    s.EmployeeName as SupervisorName

from Employee e

left join Employee s on s.EmployeeNumber = e.SupervisorNumber
```

Comment: Ok cool! So you linked the employee number and supervisor name through the join? Thanks so much